# Shell script to remove duplicate lines from a file

Tags: python, linux, shell

I have a file with output similar to below

```
<header>
    Jacob||Pune||ABC Corp||HR||33000||Lane-4, Opposite school
    Jacob||Montreal||Titan||Manager||63000||Lane-3, Near mall
    Reese||Nairobi||Reliance||Producer||35000||Sector-A, Behind post office 
    Travis||Colombo||Warner Bros||Director||7800||Near Jantar Mantar
    Jacob||Montreal||Titan||HR||63000||Lane-3, Near mall
<footer>
```

The file comprises of header, footer and in between data rows.

I want to remove duplicate rows from the file. The logic to determine if a row is duplicate or not, is to check if the combination of col 1 and col 4.

If you see there are 3 rows with value Jacob in column 1 but 2 rows have HR as value in col4.

So only 2 rows(1 & 5) are duplicate based on combination of col1 and col4. So 5th row should be removed.

How to write the shell script & python script for the same. I want the solution in both shell and python scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Using awk:

```
awk -F '|' '/<header>/ { delete map;print;next } { if (map[$1,$7]!="1") { print $0 } map[$1,$7]="1" }' file
```

Set the field delimiter to "|" and then where "" is encountered in the line, delete the array called map and skip to the next line. In all other cases, check to see if the 1st and 7th fields exist as indexes in the two dimensional array map. If they don't print the line. In all cases, set the first and second indexes of the map array to the 1st and 7th fields respectively.

Output:

```
<header>
    Jacob||Pune||ABC Corp||HR||33000||Lane-4, Opposite school
    Jacob||Montreal||Titan||Manager||63000||Lane-3, Near mall
    Reese||Nairobi||Reliance||Producer||35000||Sector-A, Behind post office
    Travis||Colombo||Warner Bros||Director||7800||Near Jantar Mantar
<footer>
```

Comment: This requires GNU awk for the multidimensional array. If you use `map[$1,$7]` then any awk will work.

Comment: Great point @glennjackman, I have amended the answer